# Pandas bar plot ignores the xlim parameter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I would like to only make a plot with only the year between 1990 and 2000.

```py
import random
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':range(1950,2020),
                   'value':[random.randint(100, 1000) for x in range(70)]})
df.plot(kind = 'bar', x = 'year', y ='value', xlim = (1990,2000))
```

Whatever I set the value of `xlim` to: `(1990,2000)` or `[1990,2000]` or `1990`, it still displays the full range of the year from 1950 to 2019.

I know that one solution is to first select only the rows of year 1990 to 2000, then make the plot, like this:

```py
df.query('1990 <= year <= 2000').plot(kind = 'bar', x = 'year', y ='value')
```

But what is the problem for the above code?

Comment: @JohanC Oh I see, I think I've got your idea. because when I try using other kind of plot such as `line` or `area`, the `xlim` works. Anyway that means the `xlim` is not applicable for `bar` graph. Thank you.

Comment: @JohanC Can you post your comment again as the answer? I would like to mark your reply as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bar plot is categorical. Internally, the bars are numbered `0,1,2,...`. Pandas' bar plot doesn't seem to look at the `xlim=` argument, but you can call `plt.xlim(40, 50)` after creating the plot.

The following code looks up the categorical position of the values to set the x limits. `0.5` is added to avoid bars cut into two.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': range(1950, 2020),
                   'value': [random.randint(100, 1000) for x in range(70)]})
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', x='year', y='value', rot=0)
ax.set_xlim(np.where(df['year'] == 1990)[0] - 0.5, np.where(df['year'] == 2000)[0] + 0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: pandas bar plot with x limits]